# Argparse install fails in anaconda 4.3 for windows, with python 3.6 (64-bit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, argparse

I installed anaconda 4.3 for windows 64-bit (python 3.6 64-bit).    I then tried to install argparse, but installation failed.  Any suggestions on what to do?  (Even an install with issues is better than no install.)  Thanks.

Here is the error message (appears to suggest argparse requires python 2.6??):

conda install argparse
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - argparse -> python 2.6*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

conda info argparse
Fetching package metadata ...........

### argparse 1.2.1 py26_0

file name   : argparse-1.2.1-py26_0.tar.bz2
name        : argparse
version     : 1.2.1
build string: py26_0
build number: 0
channel     : defaults
size        : 33 KB
arch        : x86_64
date        : 2013-02-04
license     : PSF
md5         : 7fb3d86b5777d5e0f2240f34dc335f62
platform    : win32
url         : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/argparse-1.2.1-py26_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 2.6*

### argparse 1.3.0 py26_0

file name   : argparse-1.3.0-py26_0.tar.bz2
name        : argparse
version     : 1.3.0
build string: py26_0
build number: 0
channel     : defaults
size        : 34 KB
arch        : x86_64
date        : 2015-01-05
license     : PSF
md5         : 6fd2e8bc96584cf9740e47d9fbcdfc79
platform    : win32
url         : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/argparse-1.3.0-py26_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    python 2.6*

Comment: You shouldn't need to install `argparse`.  It comes standard with Python.  Ignore the version numbers.; the standard with latest changes (not many) still has an old version number, 1.1.

Comment: ah ok, thanks hpaulj--didn't realize it was a built in.

Comment: (Don't know how to mark a comment as an answer but answered by hpaulj.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

copied from my comment:

You shouldn't need to install argparse. It comes standard with Python. Ignore the version numbers.; the standard with latest changes (not many) still has an old version number, 1.1.